# Remove a row in DataGrid when AutoGenerationColumns is enabled

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid

I am auto generating my DataGrid, and everything works fine except the fact that I want to delete some rows that their value is equal to zero. Here is what I tried, but it seems I am unable to cast DataGrid to DataGridView.

```
private void bGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, 
   DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
   {
     DataGridView grid = (DataGrid)sender;
     Int32 rowToDelete = grid.Rows.GetFirstRow( DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
     if (rowToDelete == 0)
     {
       grid.Rows.RemoveAt(rowToDelete);
     }
   }
```

Comment: Do you know how you populated the grid? Remove the item from the collection you used to populate the grid. `DataGridView` is windows forms, not WPF. It's a totally unrelated control.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, thanks. I cannot remove the data from the collection that I use, since it is needed elsewhere.

Comment: Then use a copy of it for the grid. Or filter it with a CollectionViewSource. Both of those are a much better idea than what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the value you're using to decide whether or not to hide the row is in the collection used to populate your datagrid, you could try using a DataTrigger. Where rowValue is a property in your collection, whenever the value is 0, it will collapse the row.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding rowValue}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```